# Why is the session clearing after wp_safe_redirect?

Tags: wp-redirect, session

I've been pulling my hair out with this for months now, and it's causing many issues in several places.

Can anyone tell me why after setting a $_SESSION variable, and then performing a wp_safe_redirect to the same URL, the $_SESSION is completely cleared?

I've been hearing about browser security updates that may be causing this, but I'm sure it wouldn't completley stop this from working, I just don't understand it.

Can anyone give any insight to this or how I can keep my $_SESSION flowing still when doing redirects?

**Theme functions.php file**

```
<?php

// Start session to be able to set 'country_code'
function ch_session_start() {

    if(!session_id()) {

        $sessionSet = array(
            'path' => '/',
            'domain' => $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_HOST' ],
            'secure' => TRUE,
            'httponly' => TRUE,
            'samesite' => 'Lax',    //  Strict will lose the session for some reason in some case..
            'lifetime' => 18000
        );
        ini_set( 'session.cookie_lifetime', $sessionSet[ 'lifetime' ] );
        ini_set( 'session.gc_maxlifetime', $sessionSet[ 'lifetime' ] );
        ini_set( 'session.gc_probability', 1 );
        ini_set( 'session.gc_divisor', 3 );
        ini_set( 'session.cookie_samesite', $sessionSet[ 'samesite' ] );
        session_set_cookie_params( $sessionSet );
        session_start();

    }
    
}
add_action('init', 'ch_session_start', 1);

// Set the 'country_code' session variable when flag clicked
if(isset($_POST['country_gb']) || isset($_POST['country_au']) || isset($_POST['country_us'])) {

    if(isset($_POST['country_gb'])) {
        
        $_SESSION['country_code'] = 'gb';
        
    }
    
    if(isset($_POST['country_au'])) {
    
        $_SESSION['country_code'] = 'au';
    
    }
    
    if(isset($_POST['country_us'])) {
    
        $_SESSION['country_code'] = 'us';
        
    }
    
    wp_safe_redirect('/');
    exit;
    
}

...
```

Comment: Where did you do `session_start`? check [How to use session_start in Wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11797351/how-to-use-session-start-in-wordpress), this helped me alot with sessions. WordPress doesn't play very nice with sessions thats for sure.

Comment: I've added the session_start function, which is literally just before. This is the very start of the functions.php file.

Comment: `session_start()` is inside `ch_session_start()` which gets triggered on `init` hook. Your code below runs before that probably. So you set some variables, then start the session.

Comment: I would have thought the init hook is run before anything that's just in the theme's function file? Everywhere I've sessn details how to add the session_start inside the init action

Comment: Either way, moving the session_start call outside of the init action, and just placing it in the functions file makes no change, the session is still getting lost when clicking on a flag. I don't think the init action is the culprit.